# Why sleep() in a thread cannot be interrupted by signal in my code?

Tags: linux, signals, system-calls

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int sig){
  std::cout << "handler" << std::endl;
} 

void func() {
  sleep(100);
  perror("sleep err:");
}


int main(void) {
  signal(SIGINT, handler);
  std::thread t(func);
  pthread_kill(t.native_handle(), SIGINT);
  perror("kill err:");
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

If I put sleep() inside main function, and send a signal by pressing ctrl+c, sleep will be interrupted and return immediately with perror() saying it's interrupted.

But with the code above, the "handler" in handler function will be printed, but sleep will not return and the program keeps running. The output of this program is:

```
kill err:: Success
handler
```

And if I replace sleep() with recvfrom(), recvfrom() will not be interrupted even it's inside the main thread.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void SigHandler(int sig){
  std::cout << "handler" << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
 signal(SIGINT, SigHandler);
 int bind_fd_;
 if ((bind_fd_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    std::cout << "socket creation failed " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }

  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(12345);

  if (bind(bind_fd_, reinterpret_cast<const struct sockaddr *>(&servaddr),
           sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
    std::cout << "socket bind failed " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }


  struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;    
  socklen_t cliaddr_len = sizeof(cliaddr);    
  std::vector<char> buffer(10*1024*1024,0);
  std::cout << "Wait for new request"<< std::endl;    
  int n = 0;    
  while (n == 0) {    
    std::cout << "before recvfrom" << std::endl;
    n = recvfrom(bind_fd_, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 0,    
                 reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(&cliaddr), &cliaddr_len);    
    // sleep(100);
    perror("recvfrom err: ");
    std::cout << "recv " << n << " bytes from " << cliaddr.sin_port<< std::endl;    
  }    
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code, hoping your help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the time you direct the signal to the thread, that thread has not yet proceeded far enough to block in sleep(). Chances are that it has not even been scheduled for the first time. Change the code to something like

```
std::thread t(func);
sleep(5); // give t enough time to arrive in sleep()
pthread_kill(t.native_handle(), SIGINT);
```

and you'll see what you expect.

Note that using signals in a multithreaded program is not usually a good idea because certain aspects are undefined/not-so-clearly defined.

Note also that it is not correct to use iostreams inside a signal handler. Signal handlers run in a context where pretty much nothing is safe to do, much like an interrupt service routine on bare metal. See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for a thorough explanation of that matter.

Comment: Add sleep() before pthread_kill will make sleep inside func() be interrupted, I have checked this in my code, thank you so much!! Besides, I'd like to know the best practice of how to interrupt a blocking system-call in another thread. Would it be pthread_cancel? But I found that pthread_cancel seems to cancel the whole thread immediately and the code after the system call will not be execute. Another question is, is recvfrom a special system call, as I cannot interrupt it after send a signal to it's thread (and replace it with sleep will cause the interruption).

Comment: If you pthread_cancel() a thread while it is in the middle of a critical section (holds a mutex), that thread will not get a chance to release the mutex. You can install cancellation handlers for that purpose, but I doubt this is feasible at any scale but the smallest. pthread_kill(), hm, signal handlers, hm, all not very satisfying. With pthread_kill(), I suggest you carry a thread specific *termination flag* that yu check whenever a blocking call has been EINTR'd.